# How to print node id in a block in a module?

Tags: blocks, chaos-tool-suite

I have created a ctools jump menu in a block in a module. I need to get the node id for use in the links. How can I get the node id printed in the block?

Here is my code;

```
<?php 

function boathood_block_info() {
$blocks = array();
$blocks['boathood_ABC'] = array(
'info' => t('Boathood Block'),
);
return $blocks;
}

 function boathood_block_view($delta = '') {
 $block = array();
switch ($delta) {
case 'boathood_ABC':
  $block['subject'] = '';
  $block['content'] = _boathood_BLOCK_ABC_CONTENT();
  break;
 }

  return $block;
  }

 function _boathood_BLOCK_ABC_CONTENT() {
$output = boathood_page();
 return $output;
 }

 function boathood_page() {
 global $user;
 ctools_include('ajax');  
 drupal_add_js($sample_style, 'setting');
 ctools_add_js('ctools-ajax-sample', 'ctools_ajax_sample');
 ctools_add_css('ctools-ajax-sample', 'ctools_ajax_sample');
 ctools_include('jump-menu');
 $form = drupal_get_form('boathood_jump_menu_form');
 $output .= drupal_render($form);
 return array('markup' => array('#markup' => $output));
 }

  function boathood_jump_menu_form() {

 $mynid = $node->nid;

 $url = url('node/' . $mynid);
 $url2 = url('node/' . $mynid);
 $url3 = url('node/' . $mynid);
$form_state = array();
$form = ctools_jump_menu(array(), $form_state, array($url =>    t('one!'),$url2 => t('two'),$url3 => t('three')), array());
return $form;
}
```

Comment: Is the block on a full node page (whose nid you need), or is the node embedded somewhere else in the page?

Comment: Yes the block is on a full node page whose nid I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ID of the current full-page node with [`menu_get_object`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7):

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node) {
  // Do something with $node->nid
}
```

Comment: I tried the following code:                                                                                                $node = menu_get_object();
if ($node) {
$mynid = $node->nid;  
}  But the $url doesnt recognise the $mynid variable.

Comment: Interpolation is done with double quotes (not single), so: `$url = url("node/$mynid");` or `$url = url('node/' . $mynid);` will work

Comment: Still not working. Instead the page Im being redirected is to node/%24mynid

Comment: Maybe I've put it in the wrong place? I've added your code just after `function boaterhood_jump_menu_form() { `

Comment: It's in the right place if you're seeing a nearly correct url - are you sure you've updated all 3 urls?

Comment: Almost working but it seems special characters are getting rewritten ie:  `$url3 = url("node/add/facility?og_group_boathood_ref=" . $mynid); ` is getting changed to  `node/add/facility%3Fog_group_boaterhood_ref%3D44`  when the link redirects. The node id does happen to be 44 so thats working.

Comment: Params go separately: `url('node/add/facility', array('query' => array('og_group_boaterhood_ref' => $mynid)))`

Comment: Gettting even closer... Now the only url that does not work is `url = url('node/add/classified-ad', array('query' => array('og_group_boathood_ref' => $mynid)));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37135/discussion-between-meggy-and-clive).